# C# Error - Does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have an obfuscated code, written in C#, that I need to build and make an exe. However, I am getting error when build the project in VS 2012. The error says:

Error:

> xf1555389a70c7d5a.x39b8e005139a3d89.xdd6080d77f5137d7' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'xf1555389a70c7d5a.x39b8e005139a3d89.xdd6080d77f5137d7.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.
>
> File: x39b8e005139a3d89.cs

Here is xdd6080d77f5137d7.cs File obfuscated code:

```
public class xdd6080d77f5137d7 : IEnumerable<x39b8e005139a3d89.xe657754b6d8c9c0b>, IEnumerable, IComparable, x39b8e005139a3d89.xe657754b6d8c9c0b
    {
      private readonly LOG_CODES _x9035cf16181332fc;
      private readonly BOARDS _x337e217cb3ba0627;
      private readonly DeviceMode _xa4aa8b4150b11435;

  public LOG_CODES xdc1af3a17717bf0a
  {
    get
    {
      return this._x9035cf16181332fc;
    }
  }

  public BOARDS xaf77e81a71d6921f
  {
    get
    {
      return this._x337e217cb3ba0627;
    }
  }

  public DeviceMode xad98d2ceb0921f0a
  {
    get
    {
      return this._xa4aa8b4150b11435;
    }
  }

  public xdd6080d77f5137d7(LOG_CODES code, BOARDS source, DeviceMode mode)
  {
    this._x9035cf16181332fc = code;
    this._x337e217cb3ba0627 = source;
    this._xa4aa8b4150b11435 = mode;
  }

  public xdd6080d77f5137d7(LOG_CODES code, DeviceMode mode)
  {
    this._x9035cf16181332fc = code;
    this._x337e217cb3ba0627 = BOARDS.boardNULL;
    this._xa4aa8b4150b11435 = mode;
  }

  public xdd6080d77f5137d7(LOG_CODES code, BOARDS source)
  {
    this._x9035cf16181332fc = code;
    this._x337e217cb3ba0627 = source;
    this._xa4aa8b4150b11435 = DeviceMode.None;
  }

  public xdd6080d77f5137d7(LOG_CODES code)
  {
    this._x9035cf16181332fc = code;
    this._x337e217cb3ba0627 = BOARDS.boardNULL;
    this._xa4aa8b4150b11435 = DeviceMode.None;
  }

  public int CompareTo(object obj)
  {
    x7ba9346687691c4e.x4e846d09fe48634b(obj is x39b8e005139a3d89.xdd6080d77f5137d7, "Wrong data type");
    x39b8e005139a3d89.xe657754b6d8c9c0b xe657754b6d8c9c0b = (x39b8e005139a3d89.xe657754b6d8c9c0b) obj;
    if (this.xdc1af3a17717bf0a > xe657754b6d8c9c0b.xdc1af3a17717bf0a)
      return 1;
    if (this.xdc1af3a17717bf0a < xe657754b6d8c9c0b.xdc1af3a17717bf0a)
      return -1;
    if (this.xaf77e81a71d6921f > xe657754b6d8c9c0b.xaf77e81a71d6921f)
      return 1;
    if (this.xaf77e81a71d6921f < xe657754b6d8c9c0b.xaf77e81a71d6921f)
      return -1;
    if (this.xad98d2ceb0921f0a > xe657754b6d8c9c0b.xad98d2ceb0921f0a)
      return 1;
    return this.xad98d2ceb0921f0a < xe657754b6d8c9c0b.xad98d2ceb0921f0a ? -1 : 0;
  }

  public IEnumerator<x39b8e005139a3d89.xe657754b6d8c9c0b> GetEnumerator()
  {
    throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.x05b0b83b5e6c5de6() // Also, I am getting Error at this Line. The error is: 'IEnumerable.x05b0b83b5e6c5de6' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface.
  {
    throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
  }
}
```

Please see that there are 2 Errors (First one is above `File x39b8e005139a3d89.cs` and other error is at the end of the `xdd6080d77f5137d7.cs` file. )

Comment: The errors sound straight forward, what do you not understand about them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the name must be `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable.x05b0b83b5e6c5de6`.

See: [IEnumerable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.